# How to interpret a "math word" question

Tags: meaning, mathematics

Thank you for your time. Please take a look at an LSAT sentence below:

> THE CPUE, i.e. "catch per unit effort," for any species of shark is
> the number of those sharks that commercial fishing boats catch per
> hour for each kilometer of gill net set out in the water.

So I am confused by how a calculation for a CPUE is done.

Say, a commercial fishing boat catch 100 sharks in two hours after sailing for a total of 2 kilometers. Is the CPUE here 25?

Comment: This is a question about arithmetics, not about English language.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question of arithmetic.  But, yes 100 ÷ 2 ÷ 2 = 25 sharks per hour per km

Comment: So, you want us to do your LSAT math problem for you? Get serious. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Wikipedia stub on "Catch per unit effort."

[Wikipedia catch etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_per_unit_effort)

> The main difficulty when using measures of CPUE is to define the unit of effort.

This question hinges on that definition, and the quoted paragraph doesn't really define it well enough.
The usual interpretation of "per" and "for each" would imply a division by 2 hours and 2 kilometers, and then your arithmetic would be correct. But the quoted paragraph doesn't really say that that means "sailing for two hours".
So it's a question of the technical definition of CPUE, not of ordinary English usage.